# Storing and Managing X509Certificates in .Net

Tags: c#, x509certificate, application-design

I'm in process of building a Web Api which would be used to integrate Xero with a CRM System. The Web Api would have OAuth implemented to recognise each client request. Xero Api mandates that if your application is a private application then you need to create a public/private certificate key pair.

[image]
Now we would be using the same service for a few of our clients, so which means I would need to create and save the X509certificates. Since I would need to map each certificate with a User, what would be the best way to go ahead with this? Would storing the certificates in the database make sense? Or is there a better way? I've been googling a bit and couldn't find anything, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the server as files or store it in database.
You can store it in the local system using the following code.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store ("teststore", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open (OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2 ();

X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2 ("c:\\mycerts\\*****.cer");
```

if you are going to store it in the database convert it to byte[] and store it

Comment: I do know that how we can store a X509Certificate. What I'm trying to ask is what are the best practices for storing it. Additionally the answer you've given to store it in the X509Store does not help me since there is no way for me to know which client is mapped to which certificate.